# Azure Table Storage filter bug?

Tags: c#, odata, azure-table-storage

I'm sending a query to Azure Table Storage which selects a range of entities with a condition:

```
$filter=
(PartitionKey eq 'key')
 and
(
    (
        (RowKey gt '08D372E4E0A02B2600000000')
         and
        (RowKey le '08D372E4E515E3E9FFFFFFFF')
    )
     and
    (
        (Done ne 'true')
         or
        (EndTimestamp gt '635978299756075046')
    )
)
```

I need all records in a range which either not complete (Done ne 'true') or complete after specific time (EndTimestamp gt '635978299756075046'). Done is 'bool?' and EndTimestamp is 'Int64?'.

In Fiddler I can clearly see that a record like this is returned back:

```
{  
  "PartitionKey":"key",
  "RowKey":"08D372E4E0A0B8F5002CDBE3",
  "Done":true,
  "EndTimestamp@odata.type":"Edm.Int64",
  "EndTimestamp":"635978299737021249",
}
```

What does not satisfy the EndTimestamp condition: 6359782997**37021249** is obviously less than 6359782997**56075046**.

Seems like a bug, or am I missing something?

I can do additional checks at run-time as a workaround, but (1) that defeats the purpose of filtering on server side and (2) I want to reduce the traffic and query count - there can be thousands of entities which don't satisfy the condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue, that was my mistake.
The right condition is:

```
    (Done ne true)
     or
    (EndTimestamp gt 635978299756075046L)
```

I use the `TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition` helper method, which takes in strings only, so it adds quotes to the values.